# Standard Errors in OLS models

Tags: regression, estimation, standard-error, error, estimators

Assume, we estimate the model

$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i$,

with OLS. In the case of homoscedasticity, the standard error of $\widehat{\beta}_1$ can be estimated as

$\sigma_{\widehat{\beta}_1} = \sqrt {\dfrac{\sigma_u^2}{n \sigma^2_X}} = \sqrt{ \dfrac{1}{n} \dfrac{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\widehat{u}_i^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2}}.$

My question: In the enumerator, we use the correction term $n-2$. However, in the denominator, we do not use an equivalent "degrees of freedom correction". Instead, we divide by $n$. What is the intuition that we do not need to correct for degrees of freedom in this second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n-2$ occurs because the residuals lose two degrees of freedom due to the estimation of the slope and intercept parameters. For the $X$'s the estimated parameters do not enter in.  However, if you want to use the unbiased estimate for the variance of the $X$'s, $n-1$ should be used in the denominator of the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I do not understand: we also estimate one parameter in the denominator $\bar{X}$. Is this what induces the bias you are referring to?

Comment: Under the usual OLS assumptions, there is no theoretical justification to "use the unbiased estimate for the variance of the X's."  The denominator should be understood geometrically as *the appropriate measure* of the spread of the $X_i$, not statistically as an estimator of anything.